# JavaScript .replace only replaces first Match

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
var textTitle = "this is a test"
var result = textTitle.replace(' ', '%20');
```

But the replace functions stop at the first instance of the " " and I get the

Result: `"this%20is a test"`

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong I'm sure it's a simple fix.

Comment: In this case, replace( ) is a JavaScript String method. No jQuery involved.

Comment: +1 for not using jQuery

Answer (score 299, accepted):

You need a `/g` on there, like this:

```js
var textTitle = "this is a test";
var result = textTitle.replace(/ /g, '%20');

console.log(result);
```

[You can play with it here](http://jsfiddle.net/m8UuD/), the default `.replace()` behavior is to replace only the first match, [the `/g` modifier](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) (global) tells it to replace all occurrences.

Comment: For replacing a pipe, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795749/replace-pipe-and-comma-with-regex-in-javascript).

Answer (score 11):

```
textTitle.replace(/ /g, '%20');
```

Answer (score 9):

The same, if you need "generic" regex from string :

```js
const textTitle = "this is a test";
const regEx = new RegExp(' ', "g");
const result = textTitle.replace(regEx , '%20');
console.log(result); // "this%20is%20a%20test" will be a result
```

Answer (score 5):

[From w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

The replace() method searches for *a match* between a substring (or regular expression) and a string, and replaces the matched substring with a new substring

Would be better to use a regex here then:

```
textTitle.replace(/ /g, '%20');
```

Comment: thanks for the reference, it's not an easy example to follow with the blank space being the replace value (e.g. / /g).

Answer (score 4):

Try using a regex instead of a string for the first argument.

`"this is a test".replace(/ /g,'%20')` // #=> "this%20is%20a%20test"

Answer (score 3):

For that you neet to use the g flag of regex....
Like this :

```
var new_string=old_string.replace( / (regex) /g,  replacement_text);
```

That sh

Answer (score -5):

Try using `replaceWith()` or `replaceAll()`

http://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/

Comment: Didn't he ask for a JQuery version? I don't see a .replace() in the JQuery API - that's vanilla Javascript.

Comment: @Nick Are you jealous or what? :)

Comment: @Nikita - No...this isn't at all relevant to the question.  the OP is mistaken including jQuery in there at all, this is vanilla JavaScript, having *nothing* to do with jQuery or it's replace methods...

Comment: @Nick: Fair enough I guess; I'm just trying to give him what he asked for.

Comment: @afeng - I understand that, try and read the entire question though, not the title only...the question is about the `.replace()` string operator, no jQuery involved, it's a common mix-up, unfortunately.

Comment: This is only answer that helped me.

I'm not great with JavaScript so I couldn't work out how ' ' became / /g
Presumably /  is just an escaped space character, but how do I adapt that for
textTitle.replace('abc', 'def');