# Concatenating strings with `if` statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation, string-concatenation

I'm attempting to set up a script to concatenate some variables inside a string *if they exist*, in order to place the appropriate metadata tags into a rendered HTML document.

My concatenation code is:

```js
data = "<html>\n<head>\n" + "</head>\n<body>\n\n" + paras.join("\n\n") + "\n\n</body>\n</html>";
```

I'm trying to add `if` statements like the following into it (between the first and second items):

```js
if (typeof metadata_title !== "undefined") {
    "<title>" + metadata_title + "</title>\n"
}
if (typeof metadata_author !== "undefined") {
    "<meta name=\"author\" content=\"" + metadata_author + "\"></meta>\n"
}
if (typeof metadata_date !== "undefined") {
    "<meta name=\"date\" content=\"" + metadata_date + "\"></meta>\n"
}
```

But I can't add any of these statements directly into the concatenation code 
(it throws an error: `Unexpected token (`).

How best would I go about adding statements such as these into my concatenation string?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I'd use a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation):

```
data = "<html>\n"
     + "<head>\n" 
     + ( typeof metadata_title  !== "undefined" ?  "<title>" + metadata_title + "</title>\n"                             : "" )
     + ( typeof metadata_author !== "undefined" ?  "<meta name=\"author\" content=\"" + metadata_author + "\"></meta>\n" : "" )
     + ( typeof metadata_date   !== "undefined" ?  "<meta name=\"date\" content=\"" + metadata_date + "\"></meta>\n"     : "" )
     + "</head>\n"
     + "<body>\n"
     + "\n"
     + paras.join("\n\n")
     + "\n"
     + "\n"
     + "</body>\n"
     + "</html>"
;
```

Comment: < is confused about the usage of `typeof` in this case. Why not just check to see whether or not the `var` *is* `undefined`?..

Comment: In exceptional cases (`var undefined = 'test';`) the result is wrong. Using `typeof` is saver.

Comment: If one of the variables is not defined at all you will get a `ReferenceError`.  I think this is what the OP had in mind.  Yours is perfectly fine if all three metadatas are defined, of course.

Answer (score 7):

```
data = "<html>\n<head>\n" 
    + (
        typeof metadata_title !== "undefined" ?
        "<title>" + metadata_title + "</title>\n" :
        ""
    )
    + (
        typeof metadata_author !== "undefined" ?
        "<meta name=\"author\" content=\"" + metadata_author + "\"></meta>\n" :
        ""
    )
    + (
        typeof metadata_date !== "undefined" ?
         "<meta name=\"date\" content=\"" + metadata_date + "\"></meta>\n" :
        ""
    )
    + "</head>\n<body>\n\n" 
    + paras.join("\n\n") 
    + "\n\n</body>\n</html>";
```

Answer (score 5):

I might do something a little different (a little more akin to templating), mainly because I hate concatenated HTML done with Javascript:

```
var metadata_title = "Hello";
var metadata_author = "Me";
var metadata_date = "2011-09-07";

var template = "<html>\
            <head>\
                <title>#title#</title>\
                <meta name=\"author\" content=\"#author#\"></meta>\
                <meta name=\"date\" content=\"#date#\"></meta>\
            </head>\
            <body>\
            </body>\
            </html>";

var data = template.replace("#title#", metadata_title != undefined ? metadata_title : "")
                   .replace("#author#", metadata_author != undefined ? metadata_author : "")
                   .replace("#date#", metadata_date != undefined ? metadata_date : "");
```

Sure, there's a *very* small amount of additional overhead, but to me, it's *way* more readable.

Comment: How would you get the "paras" in here?  (Not that it is hard; I'd just like to see what you'd come up with in the absence of a real tempating engine.  Cheers.)

Comment: Unless there's something I'm missing (it's late 'n I'm in need of sleep), I'd most likely simply add `#paras#` in between the `body` tags and replace it the same way other elements are replaced.. `join` just returns a string, so I'm assuming that it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Build up the entire document into an array, then join with a `"\n"` at the end.  (The rationale for this is of course to not have lots of new lines scattered all about!  And if you are on IE7 or less, `Array#join` is considerably faster than repeated string concatenation.)

Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZCbCZ/

**UPDATE** I forgot to include the "paras" in the first fiddle.  The code with the paras is here: http://jsfiddle.net/U8325/1/

For those not wishing to click through and try it out, here is the script:

```
// Not going to define metadata_author just to be saved by typeof :-)
var metadata_title = "Hello";
var metadata_date = "2011-09-07";

// Okay 3 paras for fun
var paras = ["<p>paragraph1</p>", "<p>paragraph2</p>", "<p>paragraph3</p>"];

data = ["<html>", "<head>"]

if (typeof metadata_title !== "undefined") {
    data.push("<title>" + metadata_title + "</title>");
}
if (typeof metadata_author !== "undefined") {
    data.push("<meta name=\"author\" content=\"" + metadata_author + "\"></meta>");
}
if (typeof metadata_date !== "undefined") {
    data.push("<meta name=\"date\" content=\"" + metadata_date + "\"></meta>");
}

data.push("</head>");
data.push("<body>");
paras.forEach(function (p) {data.push(p);});   // Requires ES5; use a for-loop if you don't have it
data.push("</body>");
data.push("<html>");
data = data.join("\n");
alert(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked the readability of [Demian Brecht](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7344555/621727) answer, but I would only change the string for a **regex** instead, because the replace() function only replaces the first match (see more here: [JavaScript .replace only replaces first Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214886/javascript-replace-only-replaces-first-match/3214896))

```
var metadata_title = "Hello";
var metadata_author = "Me";
var metadata_date = "2011-09-07";

var template = "<html>\
            <head>\
                <title>#title#</title>\
                <meta name=\"author\" content=\"#author#\"></meta>\
                <meta name=\"date\" content=\"#date#\"></meta>\
            </head>\
            <body>\
            </body>\
            </html>";

var data = template.replace(/#title#/g, metadata_title != undefined ? metadata_title : "")
                   .replace(/#author#/g, metadata_author != undefined ? metadata_author : "")
                   .replace(/#date#/g, metadata_date != undefined ? metadata_date : "");
```