# Replace Pipe and Comma with Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm sitting here with "The Good Parts" in hand but I'm still none the wiser.

Can anyone knock up a regex for me that will allow me to replace any instances of "|" and "," from a string.

Also, could anyone point me in the direction of a really good resource for learning regular expressions, especially in javascript (are they a particular flavour??) It really is a weak point in my knowledge.

Cheers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`str.replace(/(\||,)/g, "replaceWith")` don't forget the `g` at the end so it seaches the string globally, if you don't put it the regex will only replace the first instance of the characters.

What is saying is replace `|` (you need to escape this character) OR(`|`) `,`

[Nice Cheatsheet here](http://www.addedbytes.com/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2/png/)

Comment: Or `/[|,]/g` since it's just a single character.

Comment: @locrizak: Cheers that works.... Thanks for the resource link too. Pointy: Yeah I see yours works too. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: @James South: `[xyz]` defines a set of character, and is equivalent to `(x|y|z)` but with no grouping expression.

Answer (score 8):

The best resource I have found if you really want to understand regular expressions (and the special caveats or quirks of any of a majority of the implementations/flavors) is [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info).

If you really get into regular expressions, I would recommend the product called RegexBuddy for testing and debugging regular expressions in all sorts of languages (though there are a few things it does not *quite* support, it is rather good overall)

**Edit:**

The best way (I think, especially if you consider readability) is using a character class rather than alternation (i.e.: `[]` instead of `|`)

use:

```
var newString = str.replace(/[|,]/g, ";");
```

This will replace either a `|` or a `,` with a semicolon

The character class essentially means "match anything inside these square brackets" - with only a few exceptions.

- First, you can specify ranges of characters (`[a-zA-Z]` means any letter from `a` to `z` or from `A` to `Z`).
- Second, putting a caret (`^`) at the beginning of the character class *negates* it - it means anything *not* in this character class (`[^0-9]` means any character that is not from `0` to `9`).
- put the dash at the beginning and the caret at the end of the character class to match those characters literally, or escape them anywhere else in the class with a `\` if you prefer