# Javascript replace() only replaces first match

Tags: javascript, replace

Hello see the jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/moolood/jU9QY/

```
var toto = 'bien_address_1=&bien_cp_1=&bien_ville_1=';
var tata = toto.replace('&','<br/>');
$('#test').append(tata);
```

Why Jquery in my exemple only found one '&' and replace it?

Comment: `replace()` is ordinary Javascript, nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3214886/6908282

Answer (score 12):

Because that's how [`replace`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11) works in JavaScript. If the search argument is a string, only the first match is replaced.

To do a global replace, you have to use a regular expression with the "global" (`g`) flag:

```
var tata = toto.replace(/&/g,'<br/>');
```

Comment: me too :).... +1 and What a typing speed you got...

Comment: @pXL man you got in there.. just a bit late.. I just dint post seeing the popup.. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have learned something today ;)

Comment: @PSL  I do deleted my answer `:)`

Answer (score 3):

The code that you have written will only replace the `first instance of the string.`

Use `Regex` along with **g** will replace all the instances of the string.

```
toto.replace(/&/g,'<br/>');
```