# Using replace(), global modifier and escaped chars causing comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

having used the internet before I can work out that `replace()` only replaces the first instance of what you're looking for in a string.

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967119/why-does-javascript-replace-only-first-instance-when-using-replace), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141180/javascript-replace-only-replaces-the-first-match) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214886/javascript-replace-only-replaces-first-match) to name a few I know that you have to use the `/x/g` if you want to search & replace the whole string for `x`.

My problem is that I'm searching for two characters that get confusing. The asterisks and slash which trigger comments when either of them are used used too close together.

I haven't ever *learnt* JavaScript so if this is simple I do apologise but I have tried so many different versions of the below I honestly can't remember them all.

```
$('#answer').delay(1000).each(function(){
                              $this = $(this);
                              $this.html($this.html().replace(/\*/g, 'x').replace(/\/\/g, '÷'));
                                         });
```

When used like this `.replace('*', 'x').replace('/', '÷')` it works fine for just one result.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `/\/\//g` in the second `.replace()`?

Comment: Also, have you checked the console? This code is giving a SyntaxError.

Comment: but `//` together triggers comments also. When I escape the double the console says I'm missing `/`

Comment: `//` doesn't trigger comment if it's a part of a regex.

Comment: Using `/\/\/\/g` says "Invalid regular expression: missing /"... Using `/\/\//g`  gets "Unexpected token }" as the rest of the line is commented out past the `//`

Comment: Doesn't trigger comment, for sure. It's used a lot by everyone want to escape backslash. Are you sure that it's not a problem of your text editor?

Comment: OK... OK.. Apologies and thanks to everyone. I was misreading the console as the problem *was* an unexpected `}` but it was actually a separate problem from some code later on that had been (partially) removed. The incorrect regex made me sure that it was that and was driving me mad.

Comment: ohh... downvote :( ...possibly deserved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works exactly as you described, so if you're having problems look somewhere else. You just wrote an incorrect regular expression and did not read into the errors :) Regular expressions have to be between / symbols and those do not need escaping under any circumstance.

```
....replace(/\//g, '÷').replace(/\*/g, 'x');

"5*4/2=10".replace(/\//, '÷').replace(/\*/, 'x');
// returns "5x4÷2=10"
```

In some cases using new RegExp objects would provide better readibility, but in your case that might be clunky.

```
"5*4/2=10".replace(new RegExp('/', 'g'), '÷').replace(new RegExp('\\*', 'g'), 'x');
```