# Javascript .replace only replaces first occurrence

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a `tinyMDE textarea` that allows users to input text in Markdown. I also have an input that allows users to type a word, and when they click the "Submit" button, it'll run a `boldWord()` function that replaces all instances of that `word` with `**word**` (e.g. bolding the word in Markdown) in the original `textarea`. The issue is that `.replace` only bolds the first instance of `input.value`, but I want it to bold all instances. Here's my code:

```
function boldWord() {
            var input = document.getElementById("wordToBold"); // The input where users type a word
            var boldedText = document.getElementById("inputtext").value.replace(input.value, `**${input.value}**`); // inputtext is the ID of the Markdown textarea, input.value is the word the user wants bolded in that Markdown textarea
            tinyMDE.setContent(boldedText); // tinyMDE is a package that allows me to turn a textarea into Markdown
        }
```

For the replace line, I've tried this:

`` var boldedText = document.getElementById("inputtext").value.replace(/input.value/g, `**${input.value}**`); ``

...but it seems to interpret "input.value" as the string, "input.value", and not the variable it is referring to.

Comment: Have you considered [`.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)?

Comment: @ouroboring thanks! that worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript .replace only replaces first Match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214886/javascript-replace-only-replaces-first-match)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work by using `.replaceAll()` (as suggested by @ouroboring)